# Moving items between folders in a SharePoint 2010 list

Tags: list, sharepoint-2010

Is there a way to move items or folders around in a SharePoint 2010 list?  Either in Designer or SharePoint?  I have a single list, with multiple levels of folders and items within those folders.  Can I move an item and/or folder containing items to a different folder within that list without being required to delete the items and/or folder and manually recreate the item/folder in the new desired location?  It seems like that would be desirable functionality for list maintenance.

Comment: Given that you'd seem to prefer to resolve this without code, you'd better off posting this on Server Fault (possibly even Super User), or waiting until SharePoint Overflow is migrated across.

Answer (score 6):

Open your list in Windows Explorer. In the Ribbon on the Libary tab in "Connect & Export" - "Open with Explorer. I than add it to my favoirites so I do not have to go into SharePoint

Comment: +1 Works like a charm but doesn't seem to fit the philosophy of web-based portals.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Manage Content and Structure tool:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/work-with-site-content-and-structure-HA010131723.aspx#BM5

Comment: That seems to indicate that Manage Content and Structure is for moving among subsites.  I need to stay on the same subsite and just move items within a single list.

Comment: you can use the tool to move documents between folders in the same document library

Comment: It is not a document library, it is a custom list.

Comment: Note: Not available in Foundation.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you can try some third-part tools such as BoostSolutions list transfer, hope it can help you to solve this issue.